# How to highlight non-rectangular hotspots?

Tags: algorithm, gui

So my question is highly related to [Creating non-rectangular hotspots and detecting clicks](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6386/creating-non-rectangular-hotspots-and-detecting-clicks/6392#comment42711_6392).

Yet again, I've irregular hot-spots (think the game Risk). So basically, we can detect clicks on these hot-spots easily using color key mapping as discussed in above [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6386/creating-non-rectangular-hotspots-and-detecting-clicks/6392#comment42711_6392) which I don't have any problems implementing (which is also covered here in [details](http://www.xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=Tutorial:ColorKeyMap)).

The problem is about highlighting these irreguar hotspots. So let me explain the question a bit more - the above color key mapping [guide](http://www.xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=Tutorial:ColorKeyMap) uses this as a world map:

[image: world map]

Then the author color-maps the imaginary countries:

[image: color coded world map]

Now we can now detect the country the pointer is over. In the same article author mentions outlining countries on mouse-over. Though to get the effect, he creates unique border assets for each country - like:

[image: line drawing outlining a single country]

For the game I'm working on I'm using the same color-key mapping idea to detect hot-spots, but I didn't like the way of highlighting hot-spots. Coloring all the hot-spots is already a time-consuming job for me - as I have 25+ hot-spots for each map. Further, the need to have 25 unique border/highlight asset per hot-spot doesn't sound right.

Anyone have a better idea/suggestion on highlighting these hot-spots?

Comment: If you have the color map couldn't you just: open it up in GIMP, select by color, and add a stroke around the selection? http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Borders_On_Selections/

Comment: Can you use custom shaders?

Comment: How do you define your hotspots in code? By use of a polygon perhaps? Can't you use the polygon information to draw a fill and outline?

Comment: @classThunder, I actually don't want borders but complete highlighting.

Comment: @Drackir, yep, that's a possibility.

Comment: Roy T, the idea of color maps is all about not defining hot-spots in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating all border/highlight assets manually, you could also create them at runtime, preferably during startup/loading of the game?

To do so, I suggest you look into the [marching squares algorithm](http://devblog.phillipspiess.com/2010/02/23/better-know-an-algorithm-1-marching-squares/). By focusing on a single color (eg. treating all other colors as "background") you should be able to trace the outline of a single hotspot. Then just move on to the next color and repeat.